# Are "coded" and "encoded" synonymous?

Tags: meaning, differences, past-participles

I was creating a domain for a website, but I couldn't understand the difference (if there is any) between the words *coded* and *encoded*.

What's the right use of them? Or are they just synonyms I can use interchangeably without worrying about context or register?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [this](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=coded,encoded&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3&share=) chart shows, both terms have become far more common over recent decades...

[image]

My feeling is that *encoded* is associated with technical contexts where *the method of encryption* is more important than the encrypted information itself. Thus, from Google Books...

> [*sent a coded message*](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22fart%20in%20a%20colander%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbo=d&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22sent%20a%20coded%20message%22&oq=%22sent%20a%20coded%20message%22&gs_l=serp.3...420211.420211.16.421326.1.1.0.0.0.0.103.103.0j1.1.0...0.0...1c.1.8ghW7yYzX00&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.41248874,d.d2k&fp=f0b2d06f0baf859d&biw=1253&bih=886):4060 hits; [*sent an encoded message*](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22fart%20in%20a%20colander%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbo=d&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22sent%20an%20encoded%20message%22&oq=%22sent%20an%20encoded%20message%22&gs_l=serp.3...54359.55758.17.56620.5.5.0.0.0.0.83.283.5.5.0...0.0...1c.1.32kEbmqESOw&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.41248874,d.d2k&fp=f0b2d06f0baf859d&biw=1253&bih=886):62 hits.
>   *(The human) [genome is encoded](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22fart%20in%20a%20colander%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbo=d&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22genome%20is%20encoded%22&oq=%22genome%20is%20encoded%22&gs_l=serp.3...612325.620842.14.621296.28.28.0.0.0.1.212.1752.25j2j1.28.0...0.0...1c.1.KDHn1Uou8_o&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.41248874,d.d2k&fp=f0b2d06f0baf859d&biw=1253&bih=886) (in DNA)*:311 hits; [...genome is coded...](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22fart%20in%20a%20colander%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbo=d&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22genome%20is%20coded%22&oq=%22genome%20is%20coded%22&gs_l=serp.3...145544.145751.18.146352.2.0.2.0.0.0.0.0..0.0...0.0...1c.1.ZfO7hxTRdzI&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.41248874,d.d2k&fp=f0b2d06f0baf859d&biw=1253&bih=886):49 hits.

In more metaphorical contexts *("She declined my offer of a drink at the bar, which I took as a coded message that she didn't fancy me")*, I definitely wouldn't use *encoded*.

Answer (score 3):

They have slightly different connotations which you may want to pay attention to: **coded** is more frequently used to describe the *action* of coding (in past tense), while **encoded** is often first interpreted as an adjective describing something that has been, well, encoded. If you're a programmer, it's not very idiomatic to say "I encoded some sweet software" if you mean you wrote the code to it; and saying "That video file is coded" (instead of encoded) is misleading. So, if your dilemma is between www.peoplecodedlinux.com and www.peopleencodedlinux.com, the former is a better choice.

Answer (score -1):

First of all convert to current tense we have code and encode.
Code - To write programs but also rarely used as encode.
Encode - To transform into another format for various reasons including standards and application of the format. Or criptify. Never used as coding in context of creating programs.